# $\exists \mathbb R$ and IP

Tags: cc.complexity-theory, interactive-proofs, existential-theory-of-the-reals

We know NP$\subseteq$ [$\exists \mathbb R$](https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/Existential_theory_of_the_reals)$\subseteq$ PSPACE=IP, but is there some more direct proof for $\exists \mathbb R\subseteq$ IP?

What about the other direction, are there some Arthur-Merlin games that are in $\exists \mathbb R$?

Comment: Given how complicated the $\exists \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathrm{PSPACE}$ is, a more direct proof of $\exists \mathbb{R} \subseteq \mathrm{IP}$ would be a major result. I can't find such a proof with Google.

Comment: The art gallery problem is $\exists\mathbb{R}$-complete https://arxiv.org/pdf/1704.06969.pdf I wonder whether your question can be answered if one can design some Arthur-Merlin games for the art gallery problem.